# Story Identification YA Fantasy - two warring factions of gods and a girl who is becoming a god

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

So all I can recall was that the story revolved around two "warring" factions of gods and their chosen people. One culture believes their gods to be the only "true" gods, and the other culture believes the same about their own gods.

The story starts off with a girl who experiences a magical phenomenon and no one knows what to make of it. Later it is revealed to her that she is becoming a god and the "Gods" don't like this because she discovers that both factions of gods are the same, though they appear to the two cultures as different entities in order to cause stress/war between the nations in order to keep the people worshiping them.

Anyone have any idea what book series this is?

Comment: this sounds like maybe One Hundred Thousand Kingdoms by N.K. Jemisin

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @fbstj I was thinking the same thing...actually, reading the title, I thought "One Hundred Thousand Kingdoms isn't YA".  However, reading the description I'd say that isn't the book.

Comment: @eshier indeed the latter part of the story is somewhat different

Comment: I didn't actually finish it, but this sounds a lot like The Last Days of Magic. In that one there's a girl who's becoming the (Celtic) Morrigan, and they're at war with the British, who are allied with the Catholic church and the Nephilim. But the Celtic elves/pantheon are actually descendants of the Nephilim who ran away to Tir na Nog during the flood, and they're playing both sides.

Answer (score 5):

[Age of the Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_the_Five) by Trudy Canavan has:

1. two factions of gods, each leading their followers to war against the "false" gods, which turn out to be the same gods in different guise,
2. a young woman protagonist discovering she is gifted by her gods with a special ability,
3. the revelation that this ability means she is able to become a god.

And yes, the gods are less than amused when our protagonist discovers the truth about the becoming of gods, and even worse when she finds out who the false gods really are ...

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the book I was trying to recall! Thanks to everyone who helped narrow this down, now I can finally finish the series!

Comment: @DanielDomiguez: Would you please accept the answer, as described in [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)? With an accepted answer, it is clearly visible that the question has been solved, at least for the asker. And of course the 15 rep bonus is also nice. :)